# SHA-1 Algorithm in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone application I need to get hash using SHA-1 Algorithm. How can I do this? For example I have `string text="1234";`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485758/sha1-with-salt-on-windows-phone-7

Comment: @revolutionkpi That doesn't mean that the answer isn't helpful / right.

Comment: SHA1 is SHA1 if you need to write your own method.

Comment: in my case, as I wrote in my question I want to find out how to implement this in Windows Phone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the [`SHA1Managed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1managed(v=vs.95).aspx) class to compute the hash of a byte array. Probably do something like this:

```
var sha = new SHA1Managed(); 
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
byte[] resultHash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 
byte[] result = sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
```

Comment: there is no SHA1CryptoServiceProvider Class in Windows Phone

Comment: @KarthikKumarViswanathan, No it isn't there on Windows Phone. The only SHA implementation available on Windows Phone 7 is `SHA1Managed`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1managed%28VS.95%29.aspx) class.